# Migrating from Joomla to Wordpress advice

Tags: wordpress, joomla, migration

This is my first time migrating a website from Joomla to Wordpress. The website: www.sfspas.com

1- I am worried that the website will not transfer well or that I will loose functionalities. 
Can I duplicate the code and just transfer that version to Wordpress? (Keeping the website live via Joomla and creating in parallel a new website www.sfpsas222.com in wordpress to test things out?)

The website has to be live 24h/7 and It can't just break. How can I make sure the inventory will be uploaded correctly and the website will look as it looks now?

2- Once transferred. If I want to change the appearance of the index.php can I simply upload a newly designed index page on Wordpress? How can I go about it? Any suggestions will be highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I recently transferred one of my sites from Joomla to Wordpress and I can say, that it's not just one-click action. Both frameworks have their own structure, you can't transfer content and users directly.

In short, for transfer you need to create a simple plugin which will take all require info from Joomla (articles, users, etc.) and inject it into Wordpress database, converting prior to that, if necessary.

And no, you CAN NOT do this on 24/7 running site. Don't even think about it. Duplicate your site, convert its database to WordPress, check, that everything works properly, and only then put it online.

It's not an easy process and it requires some knowledge. Even if some kind of Joomla-Wordpress converter exists, you'll have a lot of things messed 100% guaranteed. I've made a lot of transfers in my life, so I'm pretty sure of it.

Providing you have a required knowledge of database management and PHP, just be patient and spend some time. If you don't - hire a professional. There's no easy way here, because Joomla and WordPress are like car and bike. Both are a transport, both run fast, but you can't convert one into another without any effort.